# Getting Unmatched values by comparing two ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have Compared two ArrayLists named `alStringName` and `alNameAll`

Then, added it to ArrayList named `alNameSelected` as below :

```
            for(int i=0;i<alStringName.size();i++){
                for(int j=0;j<alNameAll.size();j++){
                    if (alStringName.get(i).equals(alNameAll.get(j))) {

                        alNameSelected.add(alStringName.get(i));

                    }
                }
            }
```

Now, Its working fine. But, I have to add unmatched content or data to another ArrayList named `alNameUnknown`

How can I do that ?

Comment: using an 'else block' and the contains method ipv equals on each element comes to mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your inner loop with a 'match or not' check:

```
for(int j=0;j<alNameAll.size();j++){
                    if (alStringName.get(i).equals(alNameAll.get(j))) {

                        alNameSelected.add(alStringName.get(i));

                    }
                }
```

becomes:

```
if ( alNameAll.contains(alStringName.get(i)){
  alNameSelected.add(alStringName.get(i));
}else{
  alNameUnknown.add(alStringName.get(i));
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution :) +1